# How to set a splitView Controller to work only on iPad in Xcode 6 in a universal app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

In previous versions of Xcode I would create two separate storyboards and let one represent the iPad version of an app and the other represent the iPhone version of the app. Now I'm not sure what to do. I thought that I would create a split view controller and somehow specify when to use that split  view controller using the width and height options found at the bottom. I believe, however, that this is only used for things inside the viewControllers.

[image]

Or would I create a split view in the same storyboard and somehow indicate that this should be the initial view controller if the device is an iPad, perhaps programmatically

```
BOOL iPad = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad );
if (iPad){
    // use iPad SplitVC
}
```

Comment: You can still make a storyboard for iPhone and one for iPad in Xcode 6. Make a new project just for iPhone. Get a new storyboard, make that one for iPad, so now you have two storyboards, one for iPad and one for iPhone. Now change the app settings for iPad only, input your selected storyboard, now make it universal, and tada you have a storyboard for iPad and one for iPhone.